# Bit Operators to append two unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

If I have two things which are hex, can I someone how append their binary together to get a value?

In C++,
say I have

```
unsigned char t = 0xc2;  // 11000010
unsigned char q = 0xa3;  // 10100011
```

What I want is somehow,
`1100001010100011`, is this possible using bit-wise operators?

I want to extract the binary form of t and q and append them...

Answer (score 20):

Yes it's possible.

Just use the left-bitshift operator, shifting to the left by 8, using at least a 16-bit integer.   Then binary OR the 2nd value to the integer.

```
unsigned char t = 0xc2; // 11000010 
unsigned char q = 0xa3; // 10100011
unsigned short s = (((unsigned short)t)<<8) | q; //// 11000010 10100011
```

Alternatively putting both values in a union containing 2 chars (careful of big endian or small)  would have the same bit level result.  Another option is a char[2].

Comment: In your last sentence, assuming you're talking about unioning a char[2] with a short, it depends on endianness.

Comment: plus, if you use << 8 on an unsigned char, you end up with zero (because an unsigned char is 8 bits, you shift all the bits out of range). Cast t to a short before you do the shift.

Comment: @OJ. C math operations promote chars and short to int, so no need to cast

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating two chars:

```
unsigned char t = 0xc2;  // 11000010
unsigned char q = 0xa3;  // 10100011

int result = t;  // Put into object that can hold the fully concatenated data;
result <<= 8;     // Shift it left
result |= q;     // Or the bottom bits into place;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really work too well because the width (usually 8-bits) of the input values aren't defined. For example, why isn't your example: 0000000100000010, which would be truly appending 1 (00000001) and 2 (00000010) bit wise.

If each value does have a fixed width *then* it can be answered with bit shifting and ORing values

EDIT: if your "width" is defined the full width with all leading zero's removed, then it is possible to do with shifting and ORing, but more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the char array.

unsigned short s;
char * sPtr = &s;
sPtr[0] = t; sPtr[1] = q;

This doesn't really care about endian.. 
I'm not sure why you'd want to do this but this would work.

The problem with the bit methods are that you're not sure what size you've got. 
If you know the size.. I'd go with Brians answer

Answer (score -2):

There is no append in binary/hex because you are dealing with Numbers (can you append 1 and 2 and not confuse the resulting 12 with the "real" 12?)

You could delimit them with some special symbol, but you can't just "concatenate" them.

Answer (score -2):

Appending as an operation doesn't really make sense for numbers, regardless of what base they're in.  Using . as the concatenation operator: in your example, 0x1 . 0x2 becomes 0x12 if you concat the hex, and 0b101 if you concat the binary.  But 0x12 and 0b101 aren't the same value (in base 10, they're 18 and 5 respectively).  In general, A O B (where A and B are numbers and O is an operator) should result in the same value no matter what base you're operating in.

Comment: he's asking for it in binary =P. that is a well defined operation. this also can actually be useful when doing stuff like huffman encoding.